# Invalid amount of arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Sorry for such a noobie question, I have just never encountered this before, I look online but can only find descriptions of what argc, and argv are.

Anyway, I started a new win32 console project in visual studio 2012. I clicked empty project, and began by adding program.cpp with which the contents are the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf( "%d", argc );
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I am planning to use arguments to make a program, which is why I need argc to be working properly. The code about outputs a huge number like '21374903'. In properties -> linker -> advanced I set the entry point to 'main'.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Can I add a setting to make it work properly?

Comment: Note that you must include `<stdio.h>` for `printf` and `getchar`, and `<windows.h>` is unnecessary.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Windows.h is for SetConsoleTitle (yet to be added), and iostream holds printf, and getchar. I compiled an empty project so I don't need stdio.h :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In properties -> linker -> advanced I set the entry point to '`main`'.

Don't do that.  The entry point needs to be the C Runtime (CRT) entry point, which performs C initialization, obtains the arguments from the operating system, and calls your `main` function with them.

If you don't explicitly tell the linker what the entry point is named, it will automatically pick the right one.  The CRT entry point that calls `main` is named `mainCRTStartup` (there are other CRT entry points with other names that call the other kinds of main functions supported by Visual C++).

Comment: Wow thanks! I just assumed I had to do that. You have to define everything else (giggle).

Comment: Never bothered to tinker with the entry point, it's useful to know what it should be.

Comment: There are exceptionally few (read: extremely rare) occasions when you'd ever need to override the entry point.